I cannot connect to the selected bluetooth device
private async void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // We check if there is a selected device
     if (listBoxDevices.SelectedItem != null)
     {
         // We get the information of the selected device and save it in string format
         string selectedDevice = listBoxDevices.SelectedItem.ToString();

         // We separate device information. Here we use space character to separate device information.
         string[] deviceInfoParts = selectedDevice.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

         // We check whether the address part exists or not
         if (deviceInfoParts.Length > 1)
         {
             //We get the address information (we get the second part)
             string addressString = deviceInfoParts[1];

             // We clear the Bluetooth address and format it appropriately.
             // We remove the ":" and "-" characters and flatten the address
             addressString = addressString.Replace(":", "").Replace("-", "").Trim(); // 


             // We convert the cleaned address to ulong (unsigned long) type
             if (ulong.TryParse(addressString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out ulong bluetoothAddress))
             {
                 try
                 {

                     // We create the device ID (in hexadecimal format)
                     var deviceId = $"BluetoothLE#BluetoothDevice_{bluetoothAddress:X}";
                     MessageBox.Show(deviceId);

                     // We use device selector to find paired Bluetooth devices
                     var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false), null);

                     // We find the target device from the device list
                     var targetDevice = devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id.Contains(deviceId));

                     // Hedef cihazı bulduysak
                     if (targetDevice != null)
                     {
                         // We use the device ID to find the RFCOMM service
                         var rfcommService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(targetDevice.Id);

                         // If RFCOMM service was received successfully
                         if (rfcommService != null)
                         {
                             // We create a new StreamSocket and connect to the RFCOMM service
                              var socket = new StreamSocket();
                               await socket.ConnectAsync(rfcommService.ConnectionHostName, rfcommService.ConnectionServiceName);
                             MessageBox.Show("Connected via RFCOMM.");

                             // Once the connection is established we send data
                             var outputStream = socket.OutputStream;
                             var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream);
                             dataWriter.WriteString("Hello from the client");
                             await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

                             // Likewise we use inputStream and DataReader to get data
                             var inputStream = socket.InputStream;
                             var dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream);
                             uint size = await dataReader.LoadAsync(1024);

                             // We read the incoming data and display it on the screen with a message box.
                             if (size > 0)
                             {
                                 string receivedData = dataReader.ReadString(size);
                                 MessageBox.Show($"Received data: {receivedData}");
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 MessageBox.Show("No data received.");
                             }
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             // RFCOMM servisi alınamadıysa hata mesajı gösteriyoruz
                             MessageBox.Show("Failed to get RFCOMM service.");
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         // Hedef cihaz bulunamadıysa hata mesajı gösteriyoruz
                         MessageBox.Show("Device not found.");
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     // Bağlantı sırasında bir hata oluşursa, hata mesajını gösteriyoruz
                     MessageBox.Show($"Error connecting to device: {ex.Message}");
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 // Bluetooth adresi uygun biçimde değilse hata mesajı gösteriyoruz
                 MessageBox.Show("Bluetooth address parsing failed. Please ensure the address is in the correct format.");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             // Seçilen cihazın bilgileri geçerli değilse hata mesajı gösteriyoruz
             MessageBox.Show("Invalid device selection. Make sure the device information is correctly formatted.");
         }
     }
     else
     {
         // Hiçbir cihaz seçilmemişse kullanıcıya seçim yapması gerektiğini belirten mesaj gösteriyoruz
         MessageBox.Show("Please select a device from the list.");
     }
 }

The point where I get an error in my code is that we use the device selector to find paired Bluetooth devices, after which this selector returns device null.
What I want is not to return null in this part, but to return its value according to the course of the code and perform the connection process.
Another suggestion is that there may have been a problem encountered during the conversions. I can't solve it. I would appreciate it if you could help me.
